# mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, user-interface

I have a program to register costumers on Python with a GUI (grid), which is connected to a database. The costumer's phone number is the PRIMARY KEY in on the tables in the database.

What I'm tryin to achieve is for the output in the GUI to be that 'Customer is registered' using set. instead of the programming shutting down and giving me an error when a phone number is a duplicate entry. I've already made a 'readonly' window to display the message, but I'm struggling to find a way to make it work.

I've seen some people mention INSERT IGNORE as a solution, but this is a school assignment and we aren't allowed to use IGNORE.

Comment: you should handle that exception and show appropriate message....

Comment: Well.. That's exactly what I want to do, but don't know how.

Comment: share your existing code which you are using to insert records in DB

Comment: share your existing code which you are using to insert records in DB

Comment: [Domnius Carswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14993281/domnius-carswell) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65691179/12695027) saying "https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-integrityerror.html Here's the answer to all your problems"